# Outlook and Office 365 does not show sent items where mails were sent using a external software which is developed using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, outlook, smtp, office365, imap

We have a mail-id in our own domain. 
We configure it in outlook along with office 365.

We have using a software for our business purpose which is developed using vb.net.

Using this software, we are sending mails to our customers from the mail-id of our own (For Example user@mydomain.in).

Customers also receive the mail properly.

The problem is that we can't able to see the sent mails in our "sent items" of both outlook and office365.

Sent items does not sync.

```
        Dim mailbody As String = ""
        Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient
        Dim e_mail As New MailMessage()
        Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
       Smtp_Server.Credentials = New                 Net.NetworkCredential("user@mydomain.in", "password")

        Smtp_Server.Port = 587
        Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = True
        Smtp_Server.Host = "smtp.office365.com"
        e_mail = New MailMessage()
        e_mail.From = New MailAddress("user@mydomain.in")
        Dim attachment As System.Net.Mail.Attachment
        e_mail.To.Add(New_Enquiry.MAIL_ID.Text)
        e_mail.Subject = "Thankyou for your Enquiry"
        e_mail.IsBodyHtml = True
        Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)
```

These are the code which I have used in vb.net. 
It works properly but unable to see the sent mails in sent items.

I had used the same code for gmail also and Gmail shows the sent mails in sent items.

Kindly spot me the error.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail is special: anything you send through their SMTP server will show up in your Sent folder.  This is not standard behaviour: if you want messages to show up in your Sent folder, you have to PLACE them there, generally using IMAP and the `APPEND` command.  If you have the right access, you may be able to make some sort of server side script to do this for you, but it is not the default.

Comment: Sorry, As I am a beginner I can't follow you. You said "if you want messages to show up in your Sent folder, you have to PLACE them there" I can't get clearly in this.

Comment: Messages don't automatically show up in the sent folder.   If you want messages in your sent folder, your program has to upload them there.  An email client, like thunderbird, does this by first sending the message via SMTP to the destination, and then using IMAP to upload a second copy to the Sent folder.    Gmail is an exception in that they've done the second part automatically for you, but that is non-standard.

Comment: Let me put it differently. If something is to be in sent folder, then some program has to put it there. There aren't any rules along the lines of "server must do that" or "client must do that". Gmail does it, Exchange does not. If you want it to happen, you have to either use a server that does it or write client code that does it.

Comment: Got it. Thank you Max and arnt.